# Getting com_error when I interact with Django app

Tags: python-3.x, django, win32com

I'm getting an error when I try to use a Django app and Python 3.7.

```
com_error at /polls/
(-2147024891, 'Access is denied.', None, None)

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.1.1.100:80/polls/
Django Version: 2.2.6
Exception Type: com_error
Exception Value:    
(-2147024891, 'Access is denied.', None, None)
Exception Location: C:\Python64\Python37\lib\site-packages\appdirs.py in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32, line 481
Python Executable:  C:\Python64\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['.',
 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Pounce',
 'C:\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Python37',
 'C:\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

The app had been working fine over the past year. This is the first time I'm getting this error. I recently installed pypiwin32. Otherwise everything is the same.

Comment: please provide little more details.

Comment: I am running the app on a test server. The error is happening as the app is just starting. My code is not involved at the point the error is occurring. It looks like the error is occurring as Python is trying to get the windows folder information.